# About C3.js chart data split

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, c3.js

Since i am not familiar with C3.js library, i am bit confuse when i tried to split the Array data.

For instant i have some array value from a json.

```
    var jsondata=[[123],[45],[56],[22]];

   var jsondataName=[["apple"],["orange"],["banana"],["pear"]];
```

I tried to pass the first array **jsondata** into the chart but these values go into the same column which is not something i would like to see.

I want these array value become independent data and push the name into it

Please see the demo i made :
http://jsfiddle.net/q8h39/92/

And the result i want should looks like
[image]

Update the json data format :

```
  "Name": apple,
    "data": {
        "value": 1434,
        }
  "Name": banana,
    "data": {
        "value": 342,
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this fiddle I made for you, should help with some questions: http://jsfiddle.net/4yqwtuwq/

Comment: i know you can do this when you define the data like this, but i must call the data according to the JSON there i must pass value by using the array

Comment: Got it. You'll probably have to loop over the data and then combine it into a an array you create, then use that array for the chart data. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, i know it, `var jsondata=[[123],[45],[56],[22]];` is the generate by a for loop, i used this for the chart data but it doesn't do the job.

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 1):

You can set the JSON object to `data.json` and then set `data.keys.value` to an array of values in that JSON:

```
var jsondata = [{
  "Name": "apple",
  "data": {
    "value": 1434,
  },
}, {
  "Name": "banana",
  "data": {
    "value": 342,
  }
}];

var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    json: jsondata,
    keys: {
      value: [
        "name", "data.value"
      ]
    },
    type: "scatter"
      //hide: true
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aendrew/mz9ccbrc/

n.b., You need C3 v0.4.11 for this (the dot syntax for `keys.value` was just added), and your JSON object needs to be an array (currently it's not valid).

If you want to convert the two arrays from your initial question to that format of JSON, try this:

```
d3.zip(jsondataName, jsondata)
.map((d) => Object({name: d[0][0], data: { value: d[1][0] } }));
```